# Who writes the solicitations?

Tags: funding, nsf, nih

Who writes the solicitations for funding agencies? The program directors or possibly other invited researchers.

Comment: Depends upon the specific program, agency, and jurisdiction. I know it varies both within and across US Federal agencies. I suspect it varies across countries as well. Any way for you to make your question for focused and less broad.

Comment: @RichardErickson based on your reply, we can't even limit it to one agency, so I am not sure how to reduce it more.

Comment: What do you mean by “solicitation”? The wording of the calls for proposals possibly?

Comment: @rhialto yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to you question is that it varies both within agencies and across agencies.

I have seen program coordinators write solicitations by themselves. I have seen them ask for scientists working within the agency to help write them. I have seen them ask for external feedback on research priorities. I have also seen scientists working within agencies write their "statements of work" for small, project driven proposals.

To answer your question for a specific agency and program, I would ask their coordinator or someone within their agency. You might also be able to ask a faculty member who has served as a reviewer for an agency.